# A lower bound of the distance between 2 distinct roots of 2 distinct polynomials

Tags: polynomials, roots, computational-mathematics, estimation, resultant

Here is one of my homework in the computer algebra class:

Let $f(x),g(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be of positive degree $m,n$, and $f(\alpha)=g(\beta)=0$, where $\alpha\neq \beta$ are real. Show that
$$ |\alpha-\beta|>\frac{1}{2^{(n+1)(m+1)}||g||_1^{m}||f||_1^n}$$

Here is my solution:

Notice that $(\alpha-\beta,\beta)$ is a common root of $f(x+y)$ and $g(y)$. Hence $\alpha-\beta$ is a root of
$$ R(x):=\mathrm{Res}_y(f(x+y),g(y))=\det \big(\mathrm{Syl}_y(f(x+y),g(y))\big)$$

Now we can view $\mathrm{Syl}_y(f(x+y),g(y))$ as a matrix in $(\mathbb{Z}[x])^{(m+n),(m+n)}$. By Hadamard inequality, for $1$-norm on $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ (By 1-norm I mean $||\sum a_i x^i||_1:=\sum |a_i|$), we have:
$$\begin{aligned}
     &||R||_1\\
     &\leqslant \big(||a_m||_1+||\binom{m}{1}a_mx+a_{m-1}||_1+||\binom{m}{2}a_mx^2+\binom{m-1}{1}a_{m-1}x+a_{m-2}||_1+\dots \big)^n\cdot ||g||_1^{m}\\
     &= \big(|a_m|2^m+|a_{m-1}| 2^{m-1}+\dots+|a_0|)^n\cdot ||g||_1^{m}\\
     &\leqslant 2^{mn}||f||_1^n||g||_1^m
   \end{aligned}$$

Since $\alpha-\beta$ is a non-zero root of $R(x)$, we have:
$$ \begin{aligned}
     |\alpha-\beta|&>\frac{1}{1+||R||_\infty}\geqslant \frac{1}{1+||R||_1}\geqslant \frac{1}{2^{mn}||f||_1^n||g||_1^m+1}\\
     &>\frac{1}{2^{mn}||f||_1^n||g||_1^m\cdot2^{1+m+n}||f||_1^n||g||_1^m}=\frac{1}{2^{(n+1)(m+1)}||g||_1^{m}||f||_1^n}
   \end{aligned}$$

I find my proof strange, since I do some redundant and huge scaling in the last step. Do I miss or misuse something?

Any comments or correction are highly appreciated. THANKS!

Edit: I do some correction, now it seems more reasonable.

Comment: @Stef Thank you for your comment! I have added these details.

Comment: I haven't looked at the rest very carefully, but it looks like you used $(2^m)^n = 2^{m+n}$ instead of $2^{mn}$.

Comment: @BenjaminWright Oh thanks! That's a stupid mistake. Now the proof seems more reasonable.